# Elsa Workflow designer activity parameters are not shown on the editor

Tags: elsa-workflows

I'm embedding the Elsa 2.8 workflow designer in an application, I have the designer showing but whatever activity I choose, the parameters are not loaded. For example, the following picture shows the properties tab for SendEmail activity.

[image: Send email activity properties are not shown]

and there's an error message in the dev console as follows:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')`

and here is the code I used to embed the designer

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Workflow/Content/elsa-workflows-studio/assets/fonts/inter/inter.css">
<link href="/Workflow/Content/elsa-workflows-studio/elsa-workflows-studio.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/Workflow/Content/monaco-editor/min/vs/loader.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="/Workflow/Content/elsa-workflows-studio/elsa-workflows-studio.esm.js"></script>

<elsa-studio-root server-url="https://localhost:5001/" monaco-lib-path="Workflow/Content/monaco-editor/min">
    <elsa-studio-dashboard></elsa-studio-dashboard>
</elsa-studio-root>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message was a little confusing and misleading. It turned out the issue was the monaco editor files not being copied to the output.
After making sure the files are copied to the output it all worked as expected.